# Get rid of bad characters, but keep all characters from all languages

Tags: php

I'm trying to clean up podcast descriptions in PHP to get rid of bad characters like invisibles, emojis, random bytes, etc, to write to MySQL. The problem is podcast descriptions are in all languages and contain legit text I need to keep in every imaginable character set, probably including some unimaginable ones. I can't see a way to create either a character whitelist or a character blacklist. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can ensure your string is in UTF-8 (using `utf8_encode()` or `iconv()` for example), you can use a character *category* black-/whitelist in an expression.

To start with, I'd remove all characters in the `\p{C}` ("other") and `\p{S}` ("symbol") [categories](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php). That should grab most of the crud.

```
$description = "Some random string, with a  emoji";
$filtered = preg_replace('/[\p{C}\p{S}]/u', '', $description);
// string(33) "Some random string, with a  emoji"
```

Note that you need to use the `u` modifier.

This should be a good starting point but it's probably too rigorous. It might remove too much from the descriptions. For example, currency symbols might be valid in some economic podcast descriptions while math symbols might be absolutely essential in the descriptions for math-based podcasts.

From this you can tweak it to replace only specific subcategories if necessary. So instead of removing the entire `\p{S}` category, you might only want to remove characters in the `\p{Sk}` ("modifiers") and `\p{So}` ("other symbols") categories. Or you might want to include other categories, like `\p{Pc}` ("connector punctuation").